# Where to ask a question about Facebook?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a problem about using Facebook. However, I cannot find a suitable site on Stack Exchange to ask it on. What site should I use?

Comment: What's the nature of the question?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) may be a fit for your question, just judging by "problem using Facebook." However, be sure to read that and other topics in their help center before you post, to *make sure* your full question is on topic there.

To quote their help center:

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which
>   behaves like an application
> - Bookmarklets
> - Features of browsers which are directly related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: I actually don't need to ask the question any more. I was going to ask why I'm no longer able to write posts on public Facebook pages, but the problem has gone away by itself. It was probably just a temporary bug.